# Is the delay function in unity faster than WaitForSeconds()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project that needs delay function which is not taking long time .. I have tried using WaitForSeconds() but the result takes time too long as well.

I have already given small parameter 0.0000000001f and it still the same , nothing change.

How can I get the faster delay than this function (WaitForSeconds()) ???

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I must admit I laughed when I saw your question. ;) The difference if any waiting for 1/2 second would be negligible in the scheme of things.  However, even if waiting for 0.0000000001f was faster in Unity, just how accurate is it. More importantly, **why** are you waiting for such an tiny interval?  0.0000000001f  is smaller than the interval for 60 FPS.  Because it is sooo small, Unity will most likely complete the coroutine on the next frame!

Comment: just use a normal function haha

Comment: :)) I'm not sure what's your situation but maybe you should experiment with Invoke() and WaitForEndOfFrame()

Answer (score 1):

"*Faster delay than 0.0000000001f*" This sounds a lil confusing, because you practically don't need a delay with this time. Or maybe I just don't get it. But... well, let's try some stuff that can be useful. You could use [Invoke](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html):

```
Invoke("methodname");
```

This will be really instant. If you need a tiny hiccup, do something like this adjusting the time (in seconds) after the comma:

```
Invoke("methodname", 0.01f);
```

If you want something fixed like the Update() method, but not so fast, you can try the method [FixedUpdate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) for a fixed frame rate method.

```
FixedUpdate(){
//code here: slower than Update(); But time fixed instead of Invoke();
}
```

Or maybe try [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for a specific time stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use WaitForSeconds for this kind of purpose, because it's handled via Coroutine system in Unity and the rate of Coroutine interval checking, is almost the same with your FrameRate (around 15-30ms interval). Because Coroutines are not threads, In fact Coroutines and other stuff that are related to Monobehaviour run on same thread (main thread). So most probably if you use new WaitForSeconds(0.0001f) it's pretty much the same as new WaitForSeconds(0.01f).

I'm not sure why do you need such small delays in your program, but since that kind of delay probably won't affect your frame-rate, you can just use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...) or other sequentially delaying methods in your code. But if your application for example has a hardware connection using SerialPort in the background (which is not needed in games!) that needs small delays, you can do those works on a background thread and share the results with the main thread using dispatch queue.

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could do it is with the

```
Update() {
}
```

Function As Its Called Every Frame **;)**